# .Net Charting access image generated in another session

Tags: asp.net-mvc, charts, mschart

I have a requirement where I need to access a chart generated in one session, in another.

To explain, process A generates some HTML which includes a chart with image url /ChartImg.axd?i=chart_0_0.png&g=a40f233f40fb4995b737d284f83ab1b7

I have deleteAfterServicing=false and dir=c:\, and if I look in c:\ chart_0_0.png is there.

Now process B (therefore running in its own session) comes along an opens the HTML file, the chart 404s because (it seems) the image handler will only allow access to that chart from the session it was created in.

Is there any way to disable this behaviour?

I look forward to your response

Karl

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I solved it by doing the following:

```
    Public Overrides Sub RenderControl(writer As System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter)

        If Me.RenderToFile Then
            'Save it to a file first
            Me.SaveImage(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(RenderToFileLocation),
                         ChartImageFormat.Png)
            'Return the image urn
            writer.Write("<img src=""" & Url.Content(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ChartFilePath")) & "?c=" & Url.Content(RenderToFileLocation) & """ />")
        Else
            MyBase.RenderControl(writer)
        End If
    End Sub
```

Then from there a created a simple .net MVC handler which returned the file and deleted it
        Function Index(ByVal c As String) As ActionResult

```
        Dim dir = Server.MapPath(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ChartFilePath"))
        Dim filepath = System.IO.Path.Combine(dir, c)
        Index = MyBase.File(filepath, "image/png")

        'Delete the file
        Try
            IO.File.Delete(filepath)
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    End Function
```